# Python version is set to non-existing version i.e. python3.7.10

Tags: python, python-3.x, version, ubuntu-22.04

[The commands and their results are shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwSCY.png)

I want to change the python version to python3.9. I followed several articles for this but when I check the version it is always 3.7.10. It never changes. I deleted all the python versions and reinstalled but it didn't solve the problem. When I try to add python3.7.10 to update-alternatives list, it says the path does not exist.
I am using ubuntu-22.04. Please guide me.

Comment: What does `which python3` return? It looks like you have a python version that was installed outside of the package management system.

Comment: which python3 returned /home/sohail/anaconda3/bin/python3

Comment: Your anaconda installed python is being used over your system version. You should either remove anaconda or actually use that to manage your python versions instead of changing the system version.

Answer (score 0):

To quickly fix this issue, you can try to add the new line at the end of ~/.bashrc:
alias python3=python3.9
Besides that, you should run 'which python3' to get the exact path
Hope It's helpful to you :)